# Sybase Mobilink Hardware requirements

Tags: android, hardware, sybase, mobilink

We are planning to have a Android 4.2 - UltraliteJ - Sybase Mobilink - Sybase DB 16.0 setup.
Concurrent user sessions will be around 10K with a max upload/download size of 10Mb.

I was wondering if anyone has done this kind of setup and what should ideally be our RAM size?

Answer (score 0):

Yes we did this, and the bottleneck is not the RAM size. The minimum requirements for Sybase DB 16 will suffice. The real challenge is to properly define the upload/download scripts.